# Word Multilevel list with guiding lines

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I have very complex multilevel list with many levels (tree structure). I'd like to add some horizontal guiding lines for better visual navigation. Different bullets are not enough (also tab spacing is small, because i need some space for deeply nested items).

I don't know how to describe it by words. Please look on ASCII example below.

This is what I get now.

```
- Level 1
  - Level 2
  - Level 2
  - Level 2
    -Level 3
    -Level 3
  - Level 2
```

And this is what I'd like to achieve

```
- Level 1
| - Level 2
| - Level 2
| - Level 2
| | -Level 3
| | -Level 3
| - Level 2
```

Only solution what come into my mind is to create a table and place item text to cell which is right from row beginning by a item level number. Then style empty cells before the text vertical borders, which will become guiding lines.

This has to be done by macro, because there are hundreds up to thousands items in the list and also all cells from the text cell till end of the row need to be merged.

Source is a plaintext with leading `tabs`.

```
+---------+---------+---------+    +-----------------------------+
| Level 1 |         |         |    | Level 1                     |
|         | Level 2 |         |    |  | Level 2                  |
|         | Level 2 |         |    |  | Level 2                  |
|         | Level 2 |         | => |  | Level 2                  |
|         |         | Level 3 |    |  |  | Level 3               |
|         |         | Level 3 |    |  |  | Level 3               |
|         | Level 2 |         |    |  | Level 2                  |
+---------+---------+---------+    +-----------------------------+
```

Do you know about more elegant solution?

Thank you.

Comment: I do not know of a way to indent your numbering and have the line as well. I add that to have stable multi-level list numbering in Word you must attach each level to a separate paragraph style. Each style can only be attached to one level in one list. See http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html

Comment: You might be able to do something with SEQ fields and AutoText. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Sequence_Fields

Answer (score 0):

In order to associate differing bullet-points for each level, you need to create
a multilevel list, acceded from the Home tab, Paragraph group, by clicking
the arrow next to Multilevel List.
This will allow you to define a bullet point for level 2 that is different from
that of level 1.

[image].

For more information see Microsoft's
[Define new bullets, numbers, and multilevel lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-new-bullets-numbers-and-multilevel-lists-6c06ef65-27ad-4893-80c9-0b944cb81f5f).

This leaves still open the problem that Word only allows one character as the
bullet point.
This means that you can define `|` as the bullet point for the first level,
but you cannot define `|  |` for the second level.

The only solution here is to use pictures as the bullet points.
Use a image editor to create your bullet-points for each level.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, unfortunately this is not useful for me. The picture has fixed width. So lines are not continuous. I tried to create bullet for lvl2 2 times wider then lvl1 and deformed image (image on [ctrlv.cz](https://ctrlv.link/shots/2020/12/07/XdOe.png) )

Comment: Trust Microsoft to complicate everything. Try perhaps to attach different styles to each level. See [example](https://officemastery.com/dual-multilevel-numbering-in-word/).

Comment: Thank you for effort :) I don't want to add numbers to list (because list items are mostly numbers and it could be confusing). I'll stick with macro-adjusted table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Word's multi-level numbered list, adding text | - and spaces, but just remove the numbering field from "Enter formatting for number:" so all you have is your symbols.
[image]